# Configuração de sub pasta no htaccess

Tags: angular, htaccess

Bom tenho um hospedagem com a seguinte estrutura:

```
index.html
.htaccess
app
site
```

Bom, dentro da pasta app tenho uma aplicação compilada em Angular 7.0 e dentro da pasta site também tenho um site feito em Angular 7.0.

Bom para que o roteamento do Angular funcione tenho que fazer a seguinte configuração no `htaccess`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:css|js|map|jpe?g|gif|png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.html?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Porém não quero ter que criar um `htaccess` para cada pasta, queria fazer toda a configuração no `htaccess` que esta na raiz.

Tentei fazer da seguinte forma:

```
# Configurações do url
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

# Angular APP
RewriteBase /app/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:css|js|map|jpe?g|gif|png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app/index.html?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

# Angular Site
RewriteBase /site/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:css|js|map|jpe?g|gif|png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /site/index.html?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Porém o `htaccess` esta respeitando apenas a primeira configuração ( # Angular APP).

Tem alguma maneira de resolver isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Será que ele não está ignorando a pasta? Testa excluindo a segunda opção assim:

```
# Configurações do url
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

# Angular APP
RewriteBase /app/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/site/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:css|js|map|jpe?g|gif|png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app/index.html?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

# Angular Site
RewriteBase /site/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/app/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:css|js|map|jpe?g|gif|png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /site/index.html?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Ué deu certo, obrigado.

Comment: Por nada, basicamente removeu a URL que não esta em uso